# How to highlight a currently opened document in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have an opened document in Visual Studio 2010. How can I highlihght this document in the Solution Explorer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look in Tools/Options/Project and Solutions. Check 'Track Active Item in Solution Explorer. This is the setup for VS 2008 so I assume it's the same for VS 2010.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it does this by default.  When I installed VS2010 I selected the General Developer settings.  When you select a document in the main editor window, the same document is hightlighted in the Solution Explorer treee.

[image]

Comment: Please don't use this screenshot to steal my identity.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools—>Options, expand Projects and Solutions, select General, and then uncheck the box next to Track Active Item in Solution Explorer.

And ctrl + W + S(show Soultion Exp)